# Passing parameter to the javascript function fails

Tags: javascript, closures

```
function test() {
    var id = 123;
    var id12 = 'abcd';
    var childDiv = "";
    childDiv += '<div style="width:20px;height:20px"  onclick="newsClicked('+id12+')">Click</div>';  

    $("#mydiv").append(childDiv);

}

function newsClicked(param) {
    alert(param);
}
```

Above is the test function, test() is the function which I call inside onClick event of a test div. If I pass id which is a number(integer) it works, If I pass 
string it says reference error. Its related to closure I guess. How to solve it.
Whats happening actually here ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change:

```
childDiv += '<div style="width:20px;height:20px" onclick="newsClicked('+id12+')">Click</div>';
```

to

```
childDiv += '<div style="width:20px;height:20px" onclick="newsClicked(\''+id12+'\')">Click</div>';
```

When you append `childDiv` 1st one to div with integer as parameter the result will be:

```
<div style="width:20px;height:20px"  onclick="newsClicked(3)">Click</div>
```

which is correct, in case of string the result will be:

```
<div style="width:20px;height:20px"  onclick="newsClicked(string_as_arg)">Click</div>
```

this is not ok, because `string_as_arg` is not a variable at last not in the scope. That's why you should enclose it in apostrophes. Then the proper results will be:

```
<div style="width:20px;height:20px"  onclick="newsClicked('3')">Click</div>
<div style="width:20px;height:20px"  onclick="newsClicked('string_as_arg')">Click</div>
```

so there is no really big difference in case of integer constant but string now is properly recognised as string not as variable.

Comment: Thanks , Got it working, but I did not get what exactly is the problem, To pass as a string parameter, we need to escape it , why ?

Comment: @sat you are passing this as a string but only to concatenate different statement of code which will be executed later.

Answer (score 1):

Its working when you are passing a `number` because the `number` need not be in `quotes` but the `string` has to be in `quotes`. so to pass string you should use `escape` char `"\"`

something like :

```
newsClicked(\''+id12+'\')
```

Answer (score 1):

on you issues,

How to solve it.

*note: you can see like `\''+id12+'\'` on below code

```
function test() {
    var id = 123;
    var id12 = 'abcd';
    var childDiv = "";
    childDiv += '<div style="width:20px;height:20px"  onclick="newsClicked(\''+id12+'\')">Click</div>';  

    $("#mydiv").append(childDiv);

}

function newsClicked(param) {
    alert(param);
}
```

Whats happening actually here ?

newsClicked function will fired after DIV clicked which is recently added to dom, 
It will added to dom like

```
<div onclick="newsClicked(abcd)" style="width: 20px; height: 20px;">Click</div>
```

here, **abcd** is use like variable, but does not exist on real.

And you will get error like

**abcd is not defined**

but if you put **id** variable which is integer, it will add on dom like

```
<div onclick="newsClicked(123)" style="width: 20px; height:20px;">Click</div>
```

which is totally correct on syntax wise.

I guess, you clear on this now.

Cheers,

Comment: ok, so If integer is passed, it takes as value, not as variable, thats why it works! Phew!